# What's the best way to hide/show widgets using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I have a ListView of widgets (as you can see in the picture here https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYcXC.jpg) and when I tap on one of them, the widget expands (with a transition that is 0.3 seconds long) revealing more widgets. I was just wandering what's the best way to reveal and hide said widgets while still being able to put a transition on the showing/hiding. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think AnimatedSwitcher would suit your case. I can't say it's the best way tho.

```
AnimatedSwitcher(
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
  child: onExpand ? MoreWidget() : Offstage(),
)
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html